# Cross-platform GUI toolkit in C or C++?

Tags: c++, c, linux, user-interface

I'm looking to write some simple GUI applications in C or C++, and am stuck for choice between the cross-platform toolkits. Keep in mind that I am developing in Ubuntu, preferably without an IDE, and preferably with good cross-platform support.

What are the pros and cons of some of these toolkits? Which have you had the best experience with?

So far, I've looked into Qt, GTK+ and wxWidgets.

Comment: I'd take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3657001/comparison-of-gui-developing-tools-for-linux/3657225#3657225

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3657001/comparison-of-gui-developing-tools-for-linux

Comment: here is (good) comparison from wxWidgets site: http://wiki.wxwidgets.org/WxWidgets_Compared_To_Other_Toolkits

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have experience with Qt and wxWidgets. Both are OK for simple GUI applications, but Qt looks more professional. I like that it keeps GUI definition code in separate files (like in .NET WinForms designer), and it is not mixed with our own code. Qt Creator is good IDE which may be used also for developing non-Qt C/C++ applications.

In Ubuntu, both Qt and wxWidgets are available in the repository, and can be installed by standard way, without building the source.

Answer (score 1):

I have a friend that is programming 3D Game Engine and he is using and recommending wxWidgets. On the other hand I have some friends developing applications for Nokia Phones, and they are using QT, and recommending it too. The answer is - choose what fits you best. ;]

Answer (score 0):

since both Qt and wxWidgets have been recommended, I have only one more I know enough to recommend: Clutter. It's more of a widget toolkit, rendered in OpenGL.