# Cross-Platform GUI Engine

Tags: c++, forms, user-interface

I am looking to make a cross-platform(Windows, Linux, Mac) library for simple GUI forms.  What do you think the best library would be for a lightweight forms application?

Comment: there are so many cross-platform GUI questions on this site already. Did you first search through them before asking this question?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cross-platform GUI toolkit in C or C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3707709/cross-platform-gui-toolkit-in-c-or-c)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Qt](http://qt.nokia.com).

And close

Answer (score 1):

Most used are [Qt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qt_%28framework%29), [wxWidgets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WxWidgets).

**Edit:** i've also found [Juce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Juce).

Answer (score 0):

[Fox toolkit](http://www.fox-toolkit.org/) is another one cross platform GUI toolkit.