# Better language for developing GUI?

Tags: java, c++, python, user-interface

I need to develop a GUI that works on both Windows and Linux, for a back-end that's written in C++ and runs on Linux only.

I'm aware that I would need to use a wrapper (like Swig) if I opt for Java or Python but then again they're known to produce better GUIs than C++.

What would you suggest as the better option (for a newbie)?

Answer (score 7):

Qt (C++) might just be your best bet. Both for ease of use and portability. [Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3657001/comparison-of-gui-developing-tools-for-linux)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at MonoDevelop. Allows you to develop in C# and deploy to both Linux and Windows.

Comment: So what you're saying is that they should write a C# app for an unmanaged C++ library?

Comment: The Gui stuff should be easier in it. You can treat the C++ code as an unmanaged dll being referenced from that solution.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Priyanka did say the back-end is written in C++ but also said that it was Linux only and that the GUI needs to also work on Windows. That means the backend needs someway to communicate with the front end. It's totally possible to have a C++ service running on a Linux box that powers a C# front end on a Linux/Windows box. C# has some good GUI editors and WPF is really nice. I don't know how much of that translates to Mono though.

Comment: Take a look at zeromq for talking cross platform. That could help too.