# Developing a programme with GUI

Tags: linux, windows, macos, user-interface

I think that many students that start developing often ask themselves how to build a nice programme with a nice and friendly GUI. Well, I asked that myself and I searched on the web. I saw that there are several toolkit for create the GUI

- Gtk 2.0
- Gtk 3.0
- Qt
- WxWidgets
- Tk/Tcl

How chose which use in my programme?
Which is lighter?
Are there difference in using them in difference programming languages?

And more for more expert usage, for game could I use this or I have to use other programmes as blender or unity?

PS: I want develop my programme for Unix (Linux, Mac) and Windows, too.

PS2: I'm focused on C,C++ especially, then also on Python and more, but write in general.

Comment: If you do not want your application to look like win98, don't use tk/tcl.
There is no sense to use Gtk 2.0 over Gtk 3.0. Qt and Gtk 3.0 are nice (I haven't used wxwidgets, so I can't tell). Support of languages: Gtk 3.0 works nice with C/C++/C#/python/js/lua... and some others, while Qt works best with C++/java/python (some time ago .net bindings for Qt weren't working well).

Comment: For Linux, there's useful info here too http://stackoverflow.com/q/3657001/2065121

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, use the installed version of a toolkit on your system. Recent Linux distributions should have a *Qt4.8*  or *Qt5.0* and a *GTK3.6* or later (GTK3.8 has been released recently). Don't use GTK2.

<sup>I am focusing here on coding GUIs in C++ (in particular on Linux)</sup>

AFAIK, WxWidgets is a very clever wrapper above many other toolkits include Windows, Qt, Gtk, ... I am not sure to recommend it, unless you want portability and using system native toolkits. Tcl/Tk is tied to the Tcl scripting language.

There is also [FOX toolkit](http://www.fox-toolkit.org/) and [FLTK](http://www.fltk.org/) (both are C++ GUI toolkits), but they are not widely used.

Qt is related to and used by KDE. Gtk is related to and used by Gnome. But you can run a program using Qt on Gnome, or a program using GTK on KDE.

GTK is written in C, using its own object oriented machinery. If you want to code for GTK in idiomatic C++ consider using [GTKMM](http://www.gtkmm.org/) (a C++ wrapper above GTK).

Both Qt and GTK are very powerful toolkits. However, Qt give you a very powerful [Graphics View](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/graphicsview.html) framework (which Gtk don't have yet). That framework gives you the ability to put nested graphical items together, each having its own coordinates. In contrast, GTK provides a very powerful [Text View](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.4/TextWidgetObjects.html) mechanism, where you can mix widgets and formatted text. IMHO, GTK text view is slightly better than [QTextEdit](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtextedit.html).

For portable games you might consider also [SDL](http://www.libsdl.org/). For 3D scenes you may want to use the low level [OpenGL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenGL) which is wrapped by both GTK and Qt.

These days you could also want a web interface. [Wt](http://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt) could be useful (it has a programming style similar to Qt). And FastCGI protocol might be relevant. There are several libraries to embed an HTTP server inside your program, e.g. [libonion](http://www.coralbits.com/libonion/) or [libmicrohttpd](http://www.gnu.org/software/libmicrohttpd/)

On Linux and Unix systems (but not MacOSX which has [Quartz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartz_%28graphics_layer%29)) you should understand the concepts behind [X11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X11), even if it might become replaced by [Wayland](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wayland_%28display_server_protocol%29).

Comment: Why not GTK2, many WM still use that ex. XFCE

Comment: You can run a GTK3 application with XFCE (or other GTK2 window manager) or with KDE (or other Qt window manager).

Comment: And what is the difference between running gtk3 on gtk2 WM and gtk3 on gtk3 WM?

Comment: Tk is by no means tied to the Tcl scripting language, but it is easiest to embed the language into your C++ application.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the gentlest way of getting into this is using Python with the GUI native to whatever desktop environment is your favorite. Python is easy to program in, very powerful and flexible and handles GUIs nicely (most on my Fedora's administration tools GUIs are written in Python). For a GUI performance is normally very, very secondary. Python runs fine on Windows too.